# Encrypt Caesar VB.net

Tags: vb.net, encryption, caesar-cipher

I want to encrypt using caesar cipher with VB.net. I am successful when I input 'ABC' the result is 'def', but when I input 'XYZ' the result is still 'xyz'. When I input 'XYZ' the result should be 'abc'. Can you guys help me please?

**Source code**

```
Public Function EncCaesar(ByVal s As String) As String
        Dim charSet1 As String = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 'my input string
        Dim charSet2 As String = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 'my encrypt key
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim pos, pos2 As Integer, encryptedChar, encryptedText
        For i = 1 To Len(s)
            pos = InStr(charSet1, Mid(s, i, 1))
            pos = pos + 3
            pos2 = InStr(charSet1, Mid(s, i, 1))
            pos2 = pos - 3
            If pos > 0 Then
                If pos2 > 24 Then
                    encryptedChar = Mid(charSet2, pos2, 1)
                    encryptedText = encryptedText + encryptedChar
                Else
                    encryptedChar = Mid(charSet2, pos, 1)
                    encryptedText = encryptedText + encryptedChar
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        EncCaesar = encryptedText
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try my approach.

**Encryption:**

(code cleaned)

```
''' <summary>
''' Encrypts a string using Caesar's substitution technique.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher 
''' </remarks>
''' <param name="text">The text to encrypt.</param>
''' <param name="shift">The character shifting.</param>
''' <param name="charSet">The character set to use in encoding.</param>
''' <returns>The encrypted string.</returns>
Public Shared Function CaesarEncrypt(ByVal text As String,
                                     ByVal shift As Integer,
                                     Optional ByVal charSet As String =
                                                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" &
                                                    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" & " ") As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder With {.Capacity = text.Length}

    For Each c As Char In text

        Dim charIndex As Integer = charSet.IndexOf(c)

        If charIndex = -1 Then
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("Character '{0}' not found in character set '{1}'.", c, charSet))

        Else
            Do Until (charIndex + shift) < (charSet.Length)
                charIndex -= charSet.Length
            Loop

            sb.Append(charSet(charIndex + shift))

        End If

    Next c

    Return sb.ToString

End Function
```

**Decryption:**

```
''' <summary>
''' Decrypts a string using Caesar's substitution technique.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher 
''' </remarks>
''' <param name="text">The encrypted text to decrypt.</param>
''' <param name="shift">The character shifting to reverse the encryption.</param>
''' <param name="charSet">The character set to use in decoding.</param>
''' <returns>The decrypted string.</returns>
Public Shared Function CaesarDecrypt(ByVal text As String,
                                     ByVal shift As Integer,
                                     Optional ByVal charSet As String =
                                                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" &
                                                    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" & " ") As String

    Return CaesarEncrypt(text, shift, String.Join("", charSet.Reverse))

End Function
```

**Test usage and results:**

```
Dim value As String = "Hello World"

Dim encrypted As String = CaesarEncrypt(value, shift:=15)
Dim decrypted As String = CaesarDecrypt(encrypted, shift:=15)

Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Unmodified string: {0}", value))
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Encrypted  string: {0}", encrypted))
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Decrypted  string: {0}", decrypted))
```

> Unmodified string: Hello World
>
> Encrypted  string: WtAADokDGAs
>
> Decrypted  string: Hello World

Comment: sorry for my bad typed. Actually at my code, the lower case for key encrypting and upper case for input... so can you help me again with the code which we can determine the key for encrypting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have manipulated Ascii codes for this function.

```
Public Function encCaesar(ByVal s As String) As String
    'abc 97 to 122
    'ABC 65 to 90
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myString As String = Trim(s)
    Dim myAscii As Integer
    Dim myChar, myEncString As String
    myEncString = ""
    For i = 1 To myString.Length
        myChar = ""
        myAscii = Asc(Mid(myString, i, 1))
        Select Case myAscii
            Case 97 To 119 'smaller case a to w
                myChar = Chr(myAscii + 3)
            Case 65 To 87 'upper case A to W
                myChar = myAscii + 3
            Case 120 To 122 'smaller case x to z
                myChar = Chr((myAscii + 3) - 26)
            Case 88 To 90 ' upper case X to Z
                myChar = Chr((myAscii + 3) - 26)
            Case Else
                myChar = " "
        End Select
        myEncString = myEncString & myChar
    Next
    Return myEncString
End Function
```

Modify your code like below. This code won't work for lower case.

```
Public Function EncCaesar(ByVal s As String) As String
    's = UCase(s)
    Dim charSet1 As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC"
    Dim charSet2 As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pos, pos2 As Integer, encryptedChar, encryptedText
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        pos = InStr(charSet1, Mid(s, i, 1))
        pos = pos + 3
        pos2 = InStr(charSet1, Mid(s, i, 1))
        pos2 = pos - 3
        If pos > 0 Then
            encryptedChar = Mid(charSet2, pos, 1)
            encryptedText = encryptedText + encryptedChar
        End If
    Next i
    EncCaesar = encryptedText
End Function
```

Comment: yeah my code won't for lower case, because lower case  at my code is the key for encrypting... sorry for my bad typed. But can you help me again which we can determine the key for encrypting?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are saying.